# Can JQTouch.js interfere with links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch

I am using the database code in Jonathan Stark's book on using HTML, CSS, and Javascript to build phone apps. On his HTML page, he references jquery, jqtouch, and javascript.

On the HTML page, he creates simple links that go to the same page:

```
<li class="arrow"><a id="1" href="#date">Yesterday</a></li>
```

When I replace that with...

```
<li><a href="rc18.html"><strong>RC18 setups</strong></a></li>
```

...then the page remains; it doesn't change to the new HTML page.

So, can JQTouch.js interfere with links?

Jqtouch.js has 9 references to 'href,' but I don't know enough Javascript to understand them.

Here's an example:

```
    function showPageByHref(href, options) {
        var defaults = {
            data: null,
            method: 'GET',
            animation: null,
            callback: null,
            $referrer: null
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        if (href != '#')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                data: settings.data,
                type: settings.method,
                success: function (data, textStatus) {
                    var firstPage = insertPages(data, settings.animation);
                    if (firstPage)
                    {
                        if (settings.method == 'GET' && jQTSettings.cacheGetRequests && settings.$referrer)
                        {
                            settings.$referrer.attr('href', '#' + firstPage.attr('id'));
                        }
                        if (settings.callback) {
                            settings.callback(true);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    if (settings.$referrer) settings.$referrer.unselect();
                    if (settings.callback) {
                        settings.callback(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else if ($referrer)
        {
            $referrer.unselect();
        }
    }
```

and here:

```
    // User clicked an internal link, fullscreen mode
    if (target == '_webapp') {
        window.location = $el.attr('href');
    }
    // User clicked a back button
    else if ($el.is(jQTSettings.backSelector)) {
        goBack(hash);
    }
    // Branch on internal or external href
    else if (hash && hash!='#') {
        $el.addClass('active');
        goTo($(hash).data('referrer', $el), animation);
    } else {
        $el.addClass('loading active');
        showPageByHref($el.attr('href'), {
            animation: animation,
            callback: function(){ 
                $el.removeClass('loading'); setTimeout($.fn.unselect, 250, $el);
            },
            $referrer: $el
        });
```

He also references jquery.js, and the href instances there are extremely cryptic to me. Can you see by the code above if something is interfering with me going to another html page in the same folder of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `rel="external"` on your link, like this:

```
<li><a href="rc18.html" rel="external"><strong>RC18 setups</strong></a></li>
```

jQTouch should leave it alone then.